# How to change Git server of the Visual Studio 2015 project

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a web project of VS2015 that binded `aaa.visualstudio.com`.
and now I need to publish or change to `bbb.visualstudio.com` of the existing source.

What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

Open command line and add a new remote

```
git remote add serverB <url>
```

Now push your changes to the new remote

```
git push serverB master
```

If you want to push all your branches - check them out and than push them all

```
# loop over all the branches check them all out  
for branch in 
    `git branch -r | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; 
do 
     git checkout $branch
```

Now push all your local branches to the new remote

```
git push --all serverB
```